# flutter performance issues when focus textformfield

Tags: flutter

I built sample app for check flutter performance. It has 1 text and 1 textformfield. when focus to textformfield , it trigger rebuild multiple time.
Video flutter performance plugin: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1S3PJd6IY_1CdVaZpDJ6xP-Ce3TZKazOq/view?usp=sharing

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  late TextEditingController textEditingController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    textEditingController = TextEditingController();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Welcome to Flutter',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Welcome to Flutter'),
        ),
        body: Column(children: [
          Text("hehe"),
          TextFormField(
            controller: textEditingController,
          )
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you'll find some answers here - https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/33833
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/59327